# Book recomendation for some specific type of questions.

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

Questions regarding orthocenter, incenter and circumcenter haunt me. For example there was a question" If a triangle is inscribed in a circle of radius 1 centimeter, what is the maximum distance between orthocenter and circumcenter". Though my friend solved it for me, but I think that I am in need of practice! I searched for various euclidean geometry books like" The classical elements, Introduction to geometry by Coexter" but most of them either go too high, or remain too low. And in none of them I found questions of type mentioned above. Ofcourse I cannot persuade a writer to write a book for me, therefore i am asking for book recommendations . Please suggest me some books. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd stick with Coxeter, but would especially recommend Geometry Revisited.

Comment: But both of these are very high level, not possible at my level!

Comment: Ok, take a look at the Art of Problem Solving's Geometry book (aimed at high school).  It may not get you what you want, though they promise a sequel (Intermediate Geometry) soon.  In any event, it is a solid text with a lot of good problems.